# When push segue works, setting navigationBar hidden makes afterimage

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar

1st view set nothing.
2nd view `navigationBar` set `hidden` and it has `UIButton` works like this

```
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
}
```

In this situation, when push works `navigationBar` makes afterimage like this.

[image]

How can I disappear this black afterimage?

Answer (score 0):

Put `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];` either in `viewWillDisappear:` or `viewDidDisappear:` after calling super in each method.

EDIT:
Also try doing that in the `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` methods of the ViewController that needs the navigation bar shown.

Don't forget to remove the method that hides the navigation bar from the View Controller that you're leaving.

Comment: `viewWillDisappear`is same result and `viewDidDisappear` disappear the navigationBar after pushing completely.

Comment: I think something different method is needed. This method still make afterimage or disappear after time.